# find and replace parts of a string in sql

Tags: sql, rdlc

I'm using a Telerik RadEditor to insert text with rich formatting.  The problem is that my rdlc reports can format all of the html mark up except for `<span style="text-decoration: underline;"> Underlined this Text </span>`.  If I use `<u>Underlined this Text</u>` it renders fine on the reports, but the control will not save it in that format. (yes I know `<u>` is depreciated...).

What I'm wanting to do is update the record after it is inserted and replace any `<span style="text-decoration: underline;">` tags with `<u>` tags and their closing tags`</span>` with `</u>`.  But I'm not sure how to do this in sql.

This is what a sample saved record currently looks like:

```
Plain Text <strong> Bold Text </strong><span style="color: #ff0000;"> Color Text </span>/<em><span style="text-decoration: underline;"> Underlined and Italics Text </span></em> and <span style="text-decoration: underline;"> Underlined Only Text </span>
```

This is what a sample saved record should look like:

```
Plain Text <strong> Bold Text </strong><span style="color: #ff0000;"> Color Text </span>/<em><u> Underlined and Italics Text </u></em> and <u> Underlined Only Text </u>
```

Any ideas as to how I can do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can implement a custom content filter as shown below which will convert the span tag to U tag. Use the same approach for the other tags:

```
<telerik:radeditor runat="server"ID="RadEditor1" OnClientLoad="OnClientLoad" ContentFilters="MakeUrlsAbsolute,FixEnclosingP">  
</telerik:radeditor>
                                <script type="text/javascript">
                                    function OnClientLoad(editor, args) {
                                        editor.get_filtersManager().add(new FixUnderline());
                                    }

                                    FixUnderline = function() {
                                    FixUnderline.initializeBase(this);
                                        this.IsDom = true;
                                        this.Enabled = true;
                                        this.Name = "FixUnderline";
                                        this.Description = "This filter changes CSS underline to u tag";
                                    };
                                    FixUnderline.prototype = { _getElements: function(a, c) {
                                        var b = a.getElementsByTagName(c);
                                        if (!b) {
                                            b = a.ownerDocument.getElementsByTagName(c);
                                        } return b;
                                    }, _replaceElementWithSpan: function(l, h, k) {
                                        var m = this._getElements(l, h);
                                        var d = [];
                                        for (var b = m.length - 1; b >= 0; b--) {
                                            Array.add(d, m[b]);
                                        } for (var a = 0, c = d.length; a < c; a++) {
                                            var e = l.ownerDocument.createElement("span");
                                            e.style.cssText = k;
                                            var f = d[a];
                                            var g = f.innerHTML;
                                            if ($telerik.isIE && g == " ") {
                                                e.innerText = g;
                                            } else {
                                                Telerik.Web.UI.Editor.Utils.setElementInnerHtml(e, g);
                                            } f.parentNode.replaceChild(e, f);
                                        }
                                    }, _replaceSpanWithElement: function(o, n, f) {
                                        var q = this._getElements(o, "span");
                                        var e = [];
                                        for (var b = q.length - 1; b >= 0; b--) {
                                            Array.add(e, q[b]);
                                        } for (var a = 0, c = e.length; a < c; a++) {
                                            var m = [];
                                            var g = e[a];
                                            for (var p = 0; p < g.childNodes.length; p++) {
                                                Array.add(m, g.childNodes[p].cloneNode(true));
                                            } if (g.style.cssText.toLowerCase() == f || g.style.cssText.toLowerCase() == (f + ";")) {
                                                var h = o.ownerDocument.createElement(n);
                                                for (var d = 0; d < m.length; d++) {
                                                    h.appendChild(m[d]);
                                                } g.parentNode.replaceChild(h, g);
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }, getHtmlContent: function(a) {
                                        this._replaceSpanWithElement(a, "u", "text-decoration: underline");
                                        return a;
                                    }, getDesignContent: function(a) {
                                        this._replaceElementWithSpan(a, "u", "text-decoration: underline");
                                        return a;
                                    }
                                    };
                                    FixUnderline.registerClass("FixUnderline", Telerik.Web.UI.Editor.Filter);
                                </script>
```

See more at https://www.telerik.com/forums/underline-in-radeditor-and-telerik-reporting and https://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/editor/examples/builtincontentfilters/defaultcs.aspx